# how to get click event of asp linkbutton which is created using literal?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dynamically created linkbutton using literal in csharp.
i want its click event.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
Literal literal = new Literal();
                literal.Text = @" <asp:LinkButton runat='server' ID='addtocart' Text=''                       
                        OnClick='addtocart_Click'><img src='images/cart.gif' alt='' title='' border='0' class='left_bt' /></asp:LinkButton>";
                div.Controls.AddAt(0, lit);
}
```

i try to make event like

```
protected void addtocart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

but not working.....!
please tell me how its click event will generate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this actually produce a button? I'm not 100% sure it would..

Comment: yess it produces buttons. It works in my project. now i just want its click event.

Comment: Why don't you use real server-controls like the `LinkButton`-control and [register an event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx)? You cannot use HTML controls (your string is nothing else) on serverside.

Comment: `addtocart1[i] = new LinkButton();
                addtocart1[i].Text = "";
                addtocart1[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(addtocart_Click);`

Comment: if you do it your way you will get ***<asp:LinkButton runat*** exactly as it is on the client. don;t mix asp.net with html

Answer (score 3):

In literal text you can add only html controls, in any case you can not add server controls. Instead add your link button programatically like

```
LinkButton button = new LinkButton();
button.ID = "addcart";
...
div.Controls.AddAt(0, button);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead Literal

you can simply use LinkButton.

```
            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(addtocart_Click)
```